# How to use a CommonJS dependency without Browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

I want to use a JavaScript library in a web application which is not a single-page app and does not yet use a module loader.

But the library ([virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom)) is only published as an [npm package for Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/virtual-dom), and all the examples use `require`.

How can I use a CommonJS dependency in a client-side app that does not use Browserify or a module loader?

Answer (score 3):

Easy, simply download this file here:

https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom/blob/master/dist/virtual-dom.js

and then include it in your page:

```
<script src="virtual-dom.js"></script>
```

Now you can access it like:

```
virtualDom.create(...);
virtualDom.diff(...);
virtualDom.h(...);
virtualDom.patch(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Browserify `--standalone` [option](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) uses "a window global if no module system is found".

The [virtual-dom/dist](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom/blob/master/dist/virtual-dom.js) directory is built with the command `browserify --standalone virtual-dom index.js > dist/virtual-dom.js` and can therefore be used in this way.